# How can I identify this header?

Tags: pcb-design, header

I am trying to find 8 pin, 2.54 mm header on mouser, but had no luck. I don't really know what search keywords should I use, walked through many many pages of "2.54 mm header" results, but did not find anything similar. Maybe someone know how exactly this kind of header is called?

[image]

Comment: They are called [JST headers](https://uk.farnell.com/c/connectors/pin-headers?brand=jst-japan-solderless-terminals).

Comment: @RohatKılıç Probably not in case they are 2.54mm. JST do not have these in that pitch.

Comment: Are you sure they are 2.54mm (0.1'')? Because that would be unusual and exotic. These are typically 2.00mm. Please clarify.

Comment: Have you actually measured the header pitch to be 2.54mm? Are you trying to find connectors that fit into an existing system?

Comment: @RohatKılıç JST makes a lot of different types of connector. This is like saying "those are Molex headers" or "those are Amphenol headers."

Comment: @JYelton yes, but that specific shape/connector shown in the question is recognised as a "JST header" or "JST connector". If you google "jst header" quite possibly same shape of connectors will appear. I know JST is a brand and they make hundreds of different type connectors, but this is something like calling a vacuum cleaner "hoover".

Comment: @RohatKılıç I still don't think that helps the OP in any useful way. Looking through JST inventory for 2.54 mm pitch connectors yields nothing like those shown in the picture. They are most similar to the PH series, but those are 2.0 mm pitch. Searching for "JST header" yields various connectors, including some from the XH series which are 2.5 mm, and might be what is desired if the OP pitch measurement was inaccurate. https://hackaday.com/2017/12/27/jst-is-not-a-connector/

Comment: @Lundin -  are you talking specifically about JST headers? -- because 0.1" shrouded headers are fairly common.

Comment: TE AMP 440055 series are quite similar but are 2.0mm pitch

Comment: please add a link to the source of the picture to your question ... do not add a comment

Comment: Many Chinese companies make or sell 2.54 mm headers that they "call" JST, sometimes with 254 in the part number. They are not officially JST, but "clones" which have been modified to use 0.1 inch = 2.54 mm pitch.

Comment: I don't have any reference design or source of the image. All I have is email with this photo and a task to make PCB which would have these connectors in 2.54 mm. But since most say, that these connectors don't come in 2.54 or they are Chinese knock offs and don't have any specific name, I guess I should consider clarifying my task.

Comment: @Scott Seidman I am talking of connectors looking like those in the picture, for which the manufacturer JST does not have a version with 0.1'' pitch. Thus either these are not "JST headers" or they are not 0.1''.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you've done is posted a picture of [JST PH series](https://www.jst.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/ePH.pdf) male headers which have a 2.0 mm pitch, and then asked in your question for 2.54 mm pitch connectors. The PH series have the characteristic shrouding shown in your picture, where one side is mostly open to accept the mating connector in only one orientation.

[image: JST PH series image]

2.54 mm (0.1 inch) pitch headers rarely have this type of shrouding configuration, causing a lot of us familiar with connectors a bit of confusion trying to find what you're looking for.

You don't mention if you're trying to match an existing connector or just selecting a connector to use for a project.

There are 2.50 mm pitch headers which sometimes are used in place of 2.54 mm pitch, which sort of works for lower pin counts. (The longer the connector, the more the pitch difference adds up.) These can often have shroud configurations similar to that pictured. Examples include [JST XH series](https://www.jst.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/eXH-new.pdf) and [Molex Mini-Lock series](https://www.molex.com/content/dam/molex/molex-dot-com/en_us/pdf/datasheets/987651-9241.pdf?inline).

A bit of advice: Don't use the "search" feature on distributors when trying to find components unless you know precisely the keywords you are looking for. If you're just trying to browse connectors that meet a few criteria, you are better using the parametric search. I find [Digikey's](https://www.digikey.com/) search to be much better than [Mouser's](https://www.mouser.com/), so I'll list the process I would follow (feel free to adapt to your vendor of choice):

1. These connectors are considered "rectangular connectors" and within that category, "headers, male pins." So we start by selecting **Products > Connectors, Interconnects > Rectangular Connectors > Headers, Male Pins**
2. There are a myriad of parameters you can narrow the half-million resulting connectors down by. (I recommend selecting "stacked" instead of "scrolling" unless you really enjoy scrolling side-to-side.) The most obvious things that appear to be requirements based on your question are 8-pin, right-angle, through hole. I'm not convinced you measured the pitch correctly, or if you did, that you got a representative image of them.
3. Select **Active** from **Product Status** (Unless you're OK ordering old inventory or items that are no longer manufactured.)
4. Select **8** from **Number of Positions**
5. Select **1** from **Number of Rows**
6. Select **Through Hole, Right Angle** from **Mounting Type**
7. *Optional:* Select **In Stock** and **Exclude Marketplace Product** at the bottom. Unless you want to look at items you can't order or items to purchase from a third-party with possible annoyances like minimum order quantity, extra shipping costs or times, etc.
8. Click **Apply All**. This refreshes the list and shows a much more manageable list of ~230 connectors.
9. At this point, you can explore the pitch options more easily. If you know for certain you want **2.54 mm**, select that from **Pitch - Mating** and then look at the ~120 options. You can go back and change the selection to **2.5 mm** instead and  look at the ~20 options. Repeat as needed.

This process is just one example of how to find components or connectors using a vendor. You can of course use distributors, manufacturers, and internet searches in general, but that can involve more guesswork sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

These ones are mainly named "JST Connectors" : [here](https://uk.farnell.com/c/connectors/pin-headers?brand=jst-japan-solderless-terminals)

Comment: No, those are not 2.54mm...

Comment: JST is a manufacturer, with a catalog of many different connectors. Thus, this doesn't necessarily answer the question.